# Two different Executors

Tags: java, android, scheduledexecutorservice

I am getting information from a site using HttpURLConnection. I am using Async task and `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool`. I have two different executors. Is it right to have to different thread pools? I am asking because i see that my second executor usually executes all scheduled runnables in same time.I also use shutdownNow.

```
executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
executorHandle = executor.schedule(refresh,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

executor2 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
executorHandle2 = executor2.schedule(refresh2,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
if(executor2!=null)
   executor2.shutdownNow();
```

Can I have two executors run at the same time?

Comment: You can try running it and see if it works..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Multiple executor services can be run at the same time. If there are enough resources available.

An executor service does the core task of processing the job. Having two executor services means we can process multiple sets of jobs at a time.

We should have a multiple Executor Services only if we think that each one has their own load to share. As per the above example there are 4 threads which do the job. This can also achieved by having one executor service spawning 4 threads.